# How to change text color of dynamically generated value? - PHP

Tags: php, css

I've been trying to change the text color of a value depending on whether the value is either Approved, Pending or Rejected.

So if its Approved, I want the text color to be Green.
Red for Rejected, and Yellow for Pending.

```
$output = ""; 
$OrderStatus = array('Pending','Approved','Rejected');
/*$Approved = 'Approved';
$Reject   = 'Rejected';
$Pending = 'Pending';*/
 $statusValue = array();
 $color = "#000000";

if ($orderValue['status'] == 0) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[0];
   $color = "#00FF00";
}
elseif ($orderValue['status'] == 1) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[1];
   $color = "#FF9900";
}
elseif ($orderValue['status'] == 2) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[2];
     $color = "#FF0000";
}



/*if (in_array(0, $orderValue)) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[0];
   $color = "#00FF00";
}
elseif (in_array(1, $orderValue)) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[1];
   $color = "#FF9900";
}
elseif (in_array(2, $orderValue)) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[2];
     $color = "#FF0000";
}*/
```

And the code to display in the table:

```
   $output .= '
  <tr>  
        <td>' .'<input type="checkbox" name="orderData[]" value="'.$orderValue['order_Id'].'" />'   . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['order_Id'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['firstname'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['lastname'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['full_address'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['postcode'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['tel_no'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['mobile_no'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$newDate . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['itemName'] . '</td>
        <td>' .$orderValue['quantity'] . '</td>
        <td> <span style=\"color: '.$color.';\">' .$statusValue['0'] . '</td>'.'</span>

  </tr>';

  echo  $output;
```

Comment: Your markup looks wrong. `<td span style=\"color: $color\">' .$statusValue['0'] . '</td>'.'</span>`. What is going on with the `span` tag?

Comment: You should use CSS classes to define the style each of your states (approved, pending or rejected). Assign each relevant element the appropriate class.

Comment: I have attempted using CSS classes but to no avail, it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using double quotes (`$output .= " ... "`) to interpolate your variable, so the `$color` variable is being treated as text (literally the string "$color"). Additionally, you're using string numerals to dereference the `$statusValue` array; you need to use integers without the quotes (`$statusValue[0]` instead of `$statusValue['0']` throughout).

```
$OrderStatus = array('Pending','Approved','Rejected');
/*$Approved = 'Approved';
$Reject   = 'Rejected';
$Pending = 'Pending';*/
 $statusValue = array();
 $color = "#000000";
if (in_array(0, $orderValue)) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[0];
   $color = "#00FF00";
}
elseif (in_array(1, $orderValue)) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[1];
   $color = "#FF9900";
}
elseif (in_array(2, $orderValue)) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[2];
     $color = "#FF0000";
}


$output .= '
  <tr>  
  <td>' .'<input type="checkbox" name="orderData[]" value="'.$orderValue['order_Id'].'" />'   . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['order_Id'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['firstname'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['lastname'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['full_address'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['postcode'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['tel_no'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['mobile_no'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$newDate . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['itemName'] . '</td>
  <td>' .$orderValue['quantity'] . '</td>
  <td> <span style=\"color: '.$color.';\">' .$statusValue[0] . '</span>'.'</td>

  </tr>';

  echo  $output;
```

I'm not sure what the value of `$orderValue` is, but I assume you'll want to be storing the values in that as integers and not strings, as well. You might want to store the order status value as `$orderValue['status']` and use something like this instead:

```
if ($orderValue['status'] == 0) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[0];
   $color = "#00FF00";
}
elseif ($orderValue['status'] == 1) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[1];
   $color = "#FF9900";
}
elseif ($orderValue['status'] == 2) {
   $statusValue[] = $OrderStatus[2];
     $color = "#FF0000";
}
```

Comment: I made the changes in the code but the colors are not being applied. It simply just tells me the value in the $color variable.

Comment: @YacubAli What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: The text color of the values in the table have been changed. The value in $statusValue[0] variable remains the same.

Comment: Have you made the changes regarding storing the order status in `$orderValue['status']` or something similar? Where is the value of the order status being defined in your code?

Comment: I have a array called $orderValue which contains all my database values that i'm outputting in a table. $orderValue['orderStatus'] was the previous variable i was using to display data but it only displayed values 0, 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a broken HTML here,

```
<td span style=\"color: $color\">' .$statusValue['0'] . '</td>'.'</span>
```

Try changing it to,

```
<td> <span style=\"color: $color\">' .$statusValue['0'] . '</span></td>'
```

Comment: Can you check it through firebug?

Comment: Yes the HTML is broken, no that's not what's causing the problem... if you look at the generated source code I can almost guarantee that you'll see, literally `<td span style="color: $color"> ... `

Comment: I've made the changes and also checked in firebug, but colors are not being applied to the values.